# Make wxMenubar global for all frames

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, menubar

I am building a wx desktop application. There are two wxFrames in total. I would like to attach a menubar on the top of each frame. Currently I am adding each menubar to each frame. Is there any solution that i can only code for one menubar and attach it to all the frames?

I am using wxWidgets 3.1.3. Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with creating t2 menus?

Comment: In the future, there are more frames that i wanted to create but i want to keep the menubar content the same. It would be tedious to create one by one..

Comment: maybe you should look into the MDI? Or use Catalin' suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot attach the same menubar to multiple frames.

You can however code only once: put common code in a base class [deriving from `wxFrame`] and derive your frame from that.